# How to solve this in least steps $\sum_{r=0}^{2014} \sum_{k=0}^r (-1)^k (k+1)(k+2)\binom{2019}{r-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Find the remainder when

$$\sum_{r=0}^{2014} \sum_{k=0}^r (-1)^k (k+1)(k+2)\binom{2019}{r-k}  $$
is divided by 64.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: I think moderators closed it because, in a post, the forum wants you to explain what you've tried, Math Stack Exchange is an helping plateform, so we help you from what you tried . It is for this that they closed your question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103682/remainder-in-double-sum-having-binomial-coefficients